# Missing fields in the transformed JSON output

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule-component, mule4

I am performing XML to JSON transformations using Transform Message connector. I have created a mule-plugin for the transformations code and added it as a dependency to my application. When I deploy the application in anypoint studio(4.3.0) it is working as expected i.e. I am getting the full payload transformed to JSON. But, when I deploy the same application to ONPREM some fields of input(XML) are missing in the output(JSON). In case of  the ONPREM application I am sending the message(XML-payload) via JMS(1.7.1)-Publish by publishing it to a JMS queue where my application is listening using JMS-On New Message and using the transformations mule-plugin(added as a dependency) to transform the XML to JSON and publishing via JMS-publish to a queue where another API is listening.

I observed that when I am dividing parts of dwl in modules and importing them in a main dwl and deploying  at ONPREM the fields are missing. But, when I am using all the module's dwl code in same dwl file I am getting all the fields.

Please Help me with this.

Comment: It will be difficult that someone can assist without seeing the input, output and DataWeave scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved. There was a difference between Studio Runtime and ONPREM Runtime. When I patched the ONPREM with latest update. The Issue got Resolved.